# ¿Cuál es orden de complejidad de un algoritmo recursivo que tiene una iteración dentro?

Tags: complejidad

Tengo un algoritmo que se puede resumir en el siguiente seudocódigo:

```
algoritmo()
     if (casobase)
           O(1)
    else
           for i=0 to n
                   T(n-1)
           endfor

           O(n)
    endif
```

El caso base de la recursión toma un tiempo de ejecución constante pero en el caso general debe ejecutar n llamados recursivos, reduciendo en 1 el tamaño de la entrada. Entonces el tiempo de ejecución para el caso general corresponderían a `T(n)=n*T(n-1)+O(n)`, pero utilizando teorema maestro no puedo conseguir el valor del orden de complejidad **O()**. ¿Cómo se calcula en estos casos?

Answer (score 1):

El orden de complejidad corresponde a O(n!) debido a que se tiene lo siguiente para los distintos valores de n

```
T(1)=1*T(0)+O(n)
T(2)=2*T(1)=1*T(0)+O(n)
T(n-1)=(n-1)*T(n-2)+O(n)=(n-1)(n-2)*T(n-3)+O(n)
T(n)=n*T(n-1)+O(n)=n*(n-1)*T(n-2)+O(n)=n*(n-1)*(n-2)*T(n-3)+O(n)=~n!
```